# Can't generate database from .edmx (Npgsql 2.2.5/EF6)

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5, npgsql

I can connect to my Postgresql database just fine (I generated the .edmx this way in the first place), but I can't generate a database from the .edmx.

The error indicates that no provider with the invariant name 'Npgsql' has been found, and that the entityFramework section of Web.config should be checked for it, but as far as I can tell it's here.

This is an ASP MVC5 application, here's the Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="pgArcher" connectionString="Host=localhost;Database=Archerie;user=postgres;password=***" providerName="Npgsql" />
    <add name="ArcherieEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ArcherieEDM.csdl|res://*/ArcherieEDM.ssdl|res://*/ArcherieEDM.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;PORT=5432;TIMEOUT=15;POOLING=True;MINPOOLSIZE=1;MAXPOOLSIZE=20;COMMANDTIMEOUT=20;COMPATIBLE=2.2.5.0;HOST=localhost;DATABASE=Archerie;USER ID=postgres;PASSWORD=***&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql - .Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
      <add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" description="Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Version= 7.3.422.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you installed Npgsql and Npgsql.EntityFramework in the
  project (seems to be obvious, but I've seen some cases when people
  report errors like yours and just installed these packages in the
  "Repository" project).
- Npgsql and Mono.Security must be registered in GAC (check the version
  you are using).

And at least, add the assembly binding for Npgsql as well:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.5.0" newVersion="2.2.5.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```